# how would i set up a cooldown for my cooldown message

Tags: discord, discord.js

if a user has repeated the command while they're on a cooldown, my bot will reply with "you are executing this command too quickly!".

the problem with this is that the user can keep spamming the command, causing the bot to spam the cooldown message as well.
i'm wondering how i would send the cooldown message once (basically how dyno bot handles it).

i'm using the basic discordjs code, as can be found here: (my code is practically the same) https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/code-samples/command-handling/adding-features/12/index.js)

help is appreciated and here is a code snippet:

```js
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        return message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                description: `You're executing "${prefix}${command.name}" too quickly!`
            },
        });
    };
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#cooldowns

Comment: how would i avoid them spamming the cooldown message?

Comment: You can simply remove the message.reply() method, so the bot wont reply when they are on a cooldown

Comment: i want it to reply, just not spam the replies. i asked how i would do that since dyno bot (which i'm pretty sure uses javascript) is able to do what i'm asking for.